# Passing scope data into $http function

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm constructing elements from metadata and i need to set a calculated class for each element.

This is what I currently do,

```
var promisses =_.map(templates, function (tmpl) {
  return $http.get(tmpl.template, {
    cache   : $templateCache,
    // Generated class name is carried to the resolving function using the config
    classes : scope.generate_class(tmpl.columns)
  }).then(function (data) {
    if ( data.status != 200 )
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch template');
    var elm = angular.element(data.data);
    elm.addClass(data.config.classes);
    return elm;
  });
});

$q.all(promisses).success....
```

If I want to use `success` instead of `then` fir the `$http` bit (which evaluates in case of an error as well) how would i do that ? when using `success` the config is not carried on to the resolving function (only the data).

Thanks.

Comment: Eh... you really don't want to use `.success` here since it doesn't chain well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### From [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http):

> Returns a promise object with the standard `then` method and two http
>   specific methods: `success` and `error`. The then method takes two
>   arguments a success and an error callback which will be called with a
>   response object. The success and error methods take a single argument
>   - a function that will be called when the request succeeds or fails respectively. **The arguments passed into these functions are
>   destructured representation of the response object passed into the
>   then method**.
>
> The response object has these properties:
>
> - **data** – *{string|Object}* – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - **status** – *{number}* – HTTP status code of the response.
> - **headers** – *{function([headerName])}* – Header getter function.
> - **config** – *{Object}* – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - **statusText** – *{string}* – HTTP status text of the response.

So you can pass the config like so:

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
```

Do not throw errors when using promises, if your server doesn't return an error code you can use `q.reject` to transform it to a rejection, also `q.all` promises doesn't have a success method:

```
var promisses =_.map(templates, function (tmpl) {
  return $http.get(tmpl.template, {
    cache   : $templateCache,
    // Generated class name is carried to the resolving function using the config
    classes : scope.generate_class(tmpl.columns)
  }).then(function(res) {
    if ( res.status != 200 ) {
      return $q.reject('Failed to fetch template');
    } else {
      var elm = angular.element(res.data);
      elm.addClass(res.config.classes);
      return elm;
    }
  });
});

$q.all(promisses)
  .then(function() { ... })
  .catch(function() { .. })
```

Comment: Thanks Ilan. Wouldn't the status always be 200 if reached success ?

Comment: @haki it could be any of these success code 2xx / 304

Comment: I just followed your code I don't know what your server returns on error

Comment: I was just saying that if lets say the server returns with 404, it wont reach `success`, it will reach `error`.

Comment: Huh? You're returning a `$q.reject` from a `.success`? I'm not sure that does what you think it does.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum why not ? I'm only doing it assuming that the server returns success codes for errors

Comment: @IlanFrumer where is that return value going? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L646 :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes you are right! `success` doesn't pass anything